# "Column 'created_date_time' cannot be null" Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

views.py

```
def when(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        reportform = ReportForm(data=request.POST)

        if reportform.is_valid():
            log.debug("test:%s",reportform)
            report = reportform.save(commit=False)
            report.user = request.user
            report.save()
```

models.py is

```
class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    incident_number = models.CharField('Incident Number', max_length=100)
    device_id = models.CharField('Device Id', max_length=100)
    app_uuid = models.CharField('Unique App Id', max_length=100)
    created_date_time = models.DateTimeField('Created')
    manual_date_time = models.DateTimeField('Another time', null=True, blank=True)
    sent_date_time = models.DateTimeField('Sent')
```

In the above model`,manual_date_time` is manually enter by user.But `created_date_time` and `send_date_time` should be generated by django since that function was not yet implemented in my app,django giving the following error"`(1048, "Column 'created_date_time' cannot be null")".`

How to hardcode it using form and sent that value so that i can enter date and time manually.Want to pass the hardcoded value to both `created_date_time` and `send_date_time using form.How to solve this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can do several things to fix this:

First, you can add the attribute `auto_now=True` for Django to add automatically the `now()` date when the object is created.

```
created_date_time = models.DateTimeField('Created', auto_now=True)
```

You can also add a default value to the DateTimeField like this:

```
created_date_time = models.DateTimeField('Created', default=datetime.now)
```

and you also can add `Null=true` like it has `manual_date_time` to add it to the db with null value.

Also, you may add the date manually when you create the object like this:

```
    from datetime import datetime
    if reportform.is_valid():
        log.debug("test:%s",reportform)
        report = reportform.save(commit=False)
        report.user = request.user
        report.created_date_time = datetime.now()
        report.save()
```

The same goes for `sent_date_time` field.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @PauloBu you should not use default=datetime.now() because the function is evaluated at the moment the models are loaded. Instead use default=datetime.now

Comment: Hi,i just updated my models.py with auto_now=True,that worked for me.Thanks Paulo

Comment: You're welcome, you may take a look at this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField. You can also use auto_now_add for just setting the date when the object is first created. These are useful attributes.